# Swagger generate Node.JS Express server code

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I have Swagger 2.0 documentation, and I would like to create a Node.JS server stub from the existing Swagger spec.

When I use the [Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io/#/), it has the option to generate Node.js server stubs, but the generated file uses the connect NPM libraries.

I would prefer to use Express, and have the application folder structure of a general Express application. Is there a way to modify the generation of the Node.JS server stub to be compatible with Express?

Comment: For your suggestion, please start a discussion [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new) and we'll work with you to add the support for nodejs express framework.

Answer (score -1):

The easy answer is to change `var app = require('connect')();` to `var app = require('express')();` in `nodejs-server-server/index.js`. But it's not optimal since the generated code does not take use of the functionality of Express.

[It seems like there will be a express code generator in the next version of swagger-codegen.](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/2197)

**[You could also use swaggerize-express to do the server stub generation.](https://github.com/krakenjs/generator-swaggerize)**